# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem with MS Graph. Im trying to create an AD App, with the secrets, and the service principal.

Im using DevOps with a release, with 4 stages. In the last stage, which is the "creation of the service principal" (after App was created and so...) i get this error:

`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0436428Z Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0437341Z At D:\a_temp\7c35c69d-f2e4-4452-b160-6c78f192c351.ps1:27 char:13`
``` 2023-09-05T13:39:41.0437693Z + $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "``https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`` ... ```
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0437902Z +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0442426Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0443046Z    eption`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0443862Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0444318Z`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.0992052Z ##[debug]Exit code: 1`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.1032324Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.1798598Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.1807603Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.1896872Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]Error detected`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.1912577Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a_tasks\PowerShell_e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1\2.226.2\powershell.ps1.`
`2023-09-05T13:39:41.2221878Z ##[section]Finishing: Create Service Principal`

And mi Pshell script is this:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

# Variables
$accessToken = "$env:AccessToken"

$rAppId = Get-Content -Path "rAppObjId.txt"

# Show AppID
Write-Host "Using AppId: $rAppId"

# Request Headers
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Accept" = "text/html, application/json"
}

# Create Service Principal
$body = @{
    AppId = $rAppId
    tags = @("WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp")
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4)
```

Comment: With the "variables" im getting the values form a previous step...accessToken and AppID

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell Have you had a look at this doc on how to create the SP in Powershell? @eduard S.